# Show a subset is subspace of a vectorspace and find the dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $n>1$ be a natural number and let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ be a real scalar. 
Let $V$ be a subset of the vector space $P_n(\mathbb{R})$. Define $V$ as

$$V=\{p\in P_n(\mathbb{R}):p(\alpha)=0\}$$

Task: show that V is a sub space of $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ and find the dimension of V.

I believe I have the correct definitions but I'm not sure if I've done this correctly.

---

I know V is a subspace if the following holds

1) Vector 0 is in the subset.

2) V is closed under addition.

3) V is closed under scalar multiplication.

For (1): I have a hard time showing but from the definition of V it only contains the zero vector. Meaning it satisfies (1).

For (2): Any real scalar multiplied with the zero vector gives the zero vector, which is in $V$. Therefore it satisfies (2).

For (3): If you add two zero vectors you will always get a the zero vector.
Therefore it satisfies (3).

I'm uncertain how to find the dimension but I know how to define it using the dimension formula for V.

$L:P_n(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto (\mathbb{R})$ defined by $L(p)=p(\alpha)$.

We can use the formula: $Dim(V)=Dim(Ker(L))+Dim(L(v))$

Comment: $V$ does not only contain $0$. Say $\alpha=0$ then the vector space also contains $x$, right?

Answer (score 2):

For 1), the zero polynomial evaluated at any point is $0$, hence $0\in V$.

For 2), if $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)=0$ then $(f+g)(\alpha)=f(\alpha)+g(\alpha)=0+0=0$. Hence $f+g\in V$.

For 3), if $f(\alpha)=0$ then for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$ you have $(c\cdot f)(\alpha)=c\cdot f(\alpha)=c\cdot 0=0$. Hence $c\cdot f\in V$.

The condition that $p(\alpha)=0$ is a single linear condition on $P_n(\mathbb{R})$. Namely, if you write each polynomial as $p=a_n\cdot x^n+...+a_0$ then $p(\alpha)=0$ holds iff $\alpha^n\cdot a_n+...+a_0=0$. Hence the dimension drops by $1$, so the dimension of $V$ equals $n$. Alternatively, you can see that $p(\alpha)$ is always a scalar, i.e. in $\mathbb{R}$ and the map $L:P_n(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is onto since the scalars in $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ maps to scalars, hence by rank-nullity theorem you see that the kernel $V$ has dimension $n$.

Comment: I can follow your arguments for 1),2),3) but I don't completely understand your answer regarding the Kernel and the rank-nullity theorem.

The rank-nullity theorem is given by $dim(im(L))+dim(ker(L))=dim(V)$. And you are arguing that $dim(im(L))+dim(ker(L))=n$. Can you explain further how you arrive to that conclusion?

Comment: Note that you define $V$ as Ker$(L)$. Hence rank-nullity theorem implies dim(im($L))$+dim($V$)=dim$(P_n(\mathbb{R})$. Since im$(L)=\mathbb{R}$, its dimension is $1$, hence dim$(V)=n+1-1=n$.

Comment: I don't understand how you can define V as Ker(L) without showing it. Why is it obvious? I don't follow how you arrive to $dim(V)=n+1-1$.

Comment: I don't need to show anything. In the question YOU define $V$ as the kernel of the map $L$. I don't understand what confuses you.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused about the definition of Ker(L). The definition I know is: For a linear transformation $L:V \mapsto W$ $ker(L)$ is defined as $L^{-1}(\{0\})$.

I also do not understand how you can arrive to $dim(V)=n+1-1$. If $dim(\mathbb{R})=1$ and we defined $V$ as $Ker(L)$. Then we have $1+dim(V)=dim(V)$. But you also set $dim(P_n(\mathbb{R}))=dim(V)$ why is that?

From the above I do not understand how you arrive to $1+dim(V)=dim(V)$ => $dim(V)=n+1-1$. Unless $dim(V)=n+1$ but that would be a contradiction

Comment: You are confused with notations. The map $L$ is a surjective linear map from $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Hence rank-nullity theorem implies dim$(\mathbb{R})$+dim(Ker($L)$)=dim($P_n(\mathbb{R}))=n+1$. Hence dim(Ker$(L))=n$. But $V$ is defined as the kernel of $L$, hence dim$(V)=n$.

Comment: Okay thank you. The most right side of the equation does confuse me a bit though. I don't understand how you know/conclude that $dim(P_n(\mathbb{R}))=n+1$

Comment: $P_n(\mathbb{R})$ is spanned by the powers $\{1,x,x^2,...,x^n\}$ of $x$ and there $n+1$ many of them. Hence its dimension is $n+1$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense when you write it. I'm not sure if I could arrive to it myself yet. But thank you for the help!