# Dimension of a subspace of $P_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $n>1$ be a natural number and let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ be a real scalar. 
Let $V$ be a subset of the vector space $P_n(\mathbb{R})$. Define $V$ as

$$V=\{p\in P_n(\mathbb{R}):p(\alpha)=0\}$$

Let V be a subspace of $P_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Task: Find the dimension of V.

---

Here is what I've tried. And I was told is incorrect.

With $L:P_n(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto (\mathbb{R})$ defined by $L(p)=p(\alpha)$.

We use the formula: $Dim(V)=Dim(Ker(L))+Dim(L(v))$

We know $V=Ker(L)$. So we have $Dim(V)=Dim(V)+Dim(L(v))$.

We know that $im(L)=\mathbb{R}$ so $Dim(\mathbb{R})=1$. 
 And $Dim(P_n(\mathbb{R}))$ is spanned by $\{{1,x,x^2,...,x^n}\}$. Therefore $dim(P_n(\mathbb{R})=n+1$. So we get

$1+Dim(V)=n+1=>Dim(V)=n$. (I was told this is incorrect).

---

I was given the hint that $Dim(P_n(\mathbb{R}))$ is in fact spanned by $\{{1,x,x^2,...,x^{n-1}}\}$. So is it simple that

$dim(P_n(\mathbb{R})=n$ and therefore we have

$1+Dim(V)=n=>Dim(V)=n-1$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show a subset is subspace of a vectorspace and find the dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680986/show-a-subset-is-subspace-of-a-vectorspace-and-find-the-dimension)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but almost. I will try and figure out how to link the old one to this new one. Because In the old one I believe I arrived at the wrong conclusion, so to help others who might encounter the same mistake as I, I will try and solve it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $\dim (V)=n-1$ is correct.

Comment: I believe that you did not read most of the question. There are many false statements between the lines. The question is not finding the dimension of $V$ but finding why the proof is incorrect. Even if we only want to find the dimension of $V$, I don't think it makes sense to only answer the question in the first line and ignoring everything after it.

Comment: @Levent exactly. I would like to know why. I don't quite understand why it's spanned up to only ^n-1 and not ^n

Comment: I explained that in your previous question which is basically the same question.